# keep only one column during merge when column names are similar

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I perform a join like this:

```
df = df.merge(df2, left_on=["code"], right_on=["countryCode"],
                    how='left')
```

Both of my dataframes have a column with the same name `money`. After the join, the new df has two columns

```
money_x  and   money_y
```

one from each table joined. How can I alter this such that for any duplicate columns, only the second one stays with the original one. For example, in this case, only `money_y` from the second **df** should stay and the original name `money` should be kept instead of `money_y`.

Answer (score 0):

This will make it where the 2nd df in the merge will essentially be the same while the first df in the merge will now have a '_y' included

```
df = df.merge(df2, left_on=["code"], right_on=["countryCode"],
                    how='left', suffixes=('_y', ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

Select only the unique columns from the first DataFrame before `join`:

```
df1 = df[list(set(df.columns).difference(set(df2.columns)))]
output = df1.join(df2, left_on="code", right_on="countryCode"])
```

Comment: as I said in my question, I actually want the column from the second table since I am not sure if the data is the same or not

Comment: That's what the code does. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

You could rename the column in one of the two dataframes before merging. For example you can rename the column `code` to `countryCode` in `df` and then merge it with `df2` on the `countryCode` column.

```
df = df.rename(columns={"code":"countryCode"})\
.merge(df2, on="countryCode", how="left")
```